# Multiple definition error when using multiple versions of same library on CGO

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I am trying to use two versions of C++ library using CGO on my golang application.
I wrote wrapper of the library using Go and my application imports the wrapper program using different package name.

However, the C++ code linker generates `multiple definition` error. I think this is because the functions in both libraries have the same name (because they are same library with different versions!)

How can I fix this? I have access to the library source code, but I don't want to add the version number to all functions in the library.

Comment: Without an example I'm not sure what's going on offhand, but maybe try building them in separate Go packages, then you can import them separately.